# Task and threading troubles

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask

I'm a having some troubles using the correct code for running this method LoadSystemData but the task i use for it seems to set IsLoaded true before it has actually completed its task or so it seems to me. The keyword await keyword is probably not a good idea since this code is running in OnCreate activity

```
    if (!ClientObjects.IsLoaded) 
    {
        t = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => LoadSystemData ());
        t.Wait ();
    }


    public static async Task LoadSystemData()
    {
        await Profile.Load();
        await GroceriesHistory.Load();
        clientGroups = await Group.LoadAll();
        clientShoppingLists = await ShoppingList.LoadAll();
        IsLoaded = true;
    }
```

Comment: What do you wanna do? Should this static method be an asyncTask??

Comment: Care to explain why *await keyword is probably not a good idea since this code is running in OnCreate activity*? If I'm not wrong, your code as posted will deadlock. Btw what is your question? *I'm a having some troubles* - what are they?

Comment: I though that since the OnCreate is the first activity lifecycle method that has to be run it would be problematic to run it asynchronously, mind you my knowledge of asynchronous programming is very limited. From my test runs of the code example it appears as if the task t finishes before any of the Profile.Load() etc. have completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoadSystemData()` method will return at the first `await` statement. This is how `async` methods work. Then you wrap the call to the method in a `Task` and wait for that `Task` to complete. But note that you are waiting for the outer `Task` to complete, not the `LoadSystemData()` `Task`.

I don't know the rules for the Android `OnCreate()` method. But ideally, it's permitted for it to return before you have completed all of the initialization, which can be permitted to complete asynchronously. In that case, what you want is more like this:

```
// Guessing at method signature here...the key is to add `async`
override async void OnCreate()
{
    // some stuff

    if (!ClientObjects.IsLoaded) 
    {
        await LoadSystemData();
    }

    // some other stuff
}
```

When your `OnCreate()` method is called, it will execute all the "some stuff" code, then if it needs to call `LoadSystemData()`, it will call that method, which in turn will call the `async` `ProfileLoad()` method. At that point, `LoadSystemData()` will return *without having completed*, and `OnCreate()` will return *without having completed*.

(Note: in reality there's always a chance of the async operation completing synchronously. But for the sake of this example, I'm assuming that doesn't happen, because that's not the interesting scenario).

The caller of your `OnCreate()` method will then get to continue executing, while your `LoadSystemData()` method continues to work asynchronously. Eventually, it will complete and the framework will resume execution of the `OnCreate()` method immediately after the call to `LoadSystemData()`, allowing it to complete the rest of its work. I.e. executing the "some other stuff" code.

A much less ideal situation would be if the `OnCreate()` method was required to complete all of its initialization before returning. In that case, the fact that `LoadSystemData()` is asynchronous is not useful, but you can still at least make the code work by waiting on it synchronously. For example:

```
override void OnCreate()
{
    // some stuff

    if (!ClientObjects.IsLoaded) 
    {
        LoadSystemData().Wait();
    }

    // some other stuff
}
```

Hopefully you can use the first example, not the second.